# How implement an inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I there,

I have this scenario:

```
public class A{
  //attributes and methods
}

public class B{
  //attributes and methods

}

public class C{
  private B b;
  //other attributes and methods
}

public class D{
  private C c1, c2, c3;
  private List<A> a;
  //other attributes and methods
}
```

Every class has its own file. However, I'd like to get classes A, B and C as inner classes of class D because I'm not using them throughout the program, just in a small part of it. How should I implement them? I've read about it, but I'm still not sure about what is the best alternative:

Option 1, using static classes:

```
public class D{
  static class A{
    //attributes and methods
  }

  static class B{
    //attributes and methods
  }

  static class C{
    private B b;
    //other attributes and methods
  }

  private C c1, c2, c3;
  private List<A> a;
  //other attributes and methods
}
```

Option 2, using an interface and a class that implements it.

```
public interface D{
  class A{
    //attributes and methods
  }

  class B{
    //attributes and methods
  }

  class C{
    private B b;
    //other attributes and methods
  }

}

public class Dimpl implements D{
  private C c1, c2, c3;
  private List<A> a;
  //other attributes and methods
}
```

I'd like to know which approach is better in order to get the same behavior using the original scenario. Is it ok if I use Option 1 and use the classes like this?

```
public method(){
  List<D.A> list_A = new ArrayList<D.A>();
  D.B obj_B = new D.B();
  D.C obj_C1 = new D.C(obj_B);
  D.C obj_C2 = new D.C(obj_B);
  D.C obj_C3 = new D.C(obj_B);

  D obj_D = new D(obj_C1, obj_C2, obj_C3, list_A);
}
```

Basicly, my concern is how the creation of inner classes will affect the outter class. In the original scenario, I first create the instances of classes A, B and C, then the instance of class D. Can I do the same with the options I mentioned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are only going to use them inside the class, you have no reason to use interface, as interface is intended for `public` access. Use your first approach (and make the classes **private** static)

Comment: +1 Adding `private` is the only thing that I would change in the otherwise good "Option 1" implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I'm going to create instances of A, B and C outside D. In summary, I'd like to get all the classes in just one java file but acting as if they were in different java files.

Comment: @sosegon - If this is the case, you should probably avoid it, separate them to different files, it's better, clearer, and easier to maintain.

Comment: @Binyamin Sharet thanks. I'm just exploring new ways to accomplish something. Finally, in which case(s) static inner classes are useful?

Answer (score 0):

Inner Classes are of 2 Types:

1. Static Inner Classes (Known as Top Level Classes)
2. Inner Classes

Static Inner Class Example:

```
   public class A {

                static int x = 5;

                int y = 10;


                static class B {

              A a = new A();       // Needed to access the non static Outer class data

              System.out.println(a.y);

              System.out.println(x); // No object of outer class is needed to access static memeber of the Outer class

    }
```

}

Inner Class Example:

```
            public class A {

                      int x = 10;

                    public class B{

                      int x = 5;

               System.out.println(this.x);
               System.out.println(A.this.x);  // Inner classes have implicit reference to the outer class

              }
          }
```

To create an objec of the Inner Class (NOT STATIC INNER CLASS), from outside, the outer class objec is needed to be created first.

A a = new A();

A.B b = a.new B();